# C# Youtube API Errors

Tags: c#, .net, api, youtube

When I want to write code with the YouTube API, I get these errors in namespace

```
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
```

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'v3' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Google.Apis.YouTube' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'v3' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Google.Apis.YouTube' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

it seems these "v3" tags does not exist so please help me

Comment: Silly question...but have you added the relevant Google API `DLL` files to your project references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sure you have the correct libraries and dependencies, try downloading the Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 Client Library through NuGet. Here is what you do:

[image]

and then enter `Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3` into the console and press enter. You should see something like this:

[image]

After the install completes, the references should have been added to the project that you have open and all you need to do is add your using statements:

```
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
```